# KDB/Q: create a new column based on the value of other columns

Tags: kdb

This might be a simple question but I cannot get it to work. I am trying to create a column `varNew` that equals half of a column `Price` if only one of the columns `var1` and `var2` has a value of 1. `var1` and `var2` only takes a value of 0 or 1. If both `var1` and `var2` are 1 then `varNew = Price`. so the wanted data looks like this

```
var1    var2    Price   varNew
0       0       10      10
0       1       14      7
1       0       12      6
1       1       20      20
```

I tried:

`update varNew:?[((var1+var2)>0);Price%2;Price] from table` and

`varNew:?[(var1=1 and var2=0)|(var1=0 and var2=1);Price%2;Price] from table` and

`varNew:?[var1=1 or var2=1;Price%2;Price] from table`

but they don not work as expected. particularly, it returns 12 instead of 6.
What is going on? why these conditions dont work? and how should I do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A solution is:

```
 q)t:([]var1:0011b;var2:0101b;Price:10 14 12 20)
 q)update varNew:?[var1<>var2;Price%2;Price] from t
```

This is one of the many overloads of the ? operator (https://code.kx.com/q/ref/overloads/#query). In this form it is used as a vector conditional.

Answer (score 4):

To provide further explanation as to why your approaches were not working

```
update varNew:?[((var1+var2)>0);Price%2;Price] from table
```

`(var1+var2)>0` includes both var1 and var2 being equal to 1, resulting in the last Price being divided by 2, when this is not the intention

```
varNew:?[(var1=1 and var2=0)|(var1=0 and var2=1);Price%2;Price] from table
```

q evaluates from right to left (also called [Left-of-Right evaluation](https://code.kx.com/q4m3/4_Operators/#412-left-of-right-evaluation)), meaning your code is actually executing this (once implicit brackets are added in)

```
var1=1 and var2=0 => (var1=(1 and (var2=0)))
var1=0 and var2=1 => (var1=(0 and (var2=1)))
```

The `1 and` will always leave the right hand side unchanged and the `0 and` on the second row will always return 0, so the whole line simplifies to:

```
varNew:?[(var1=(var2=0))|(var1=0);Price%2;Price] from table
```

Which is different to the condition you are trying to code. To fix this, you can add in extra brackets to ensure this evaluates as you expect it to, although Dan's answer is more efficient

```
varNew:?[((var1=1) and var2=0)|((var1=0) and var2=1);Price%2;Price] from table
```